# default openMPI over a big machine has a strange results

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, distributed, openmpi

I'm using a simple benchmark over multiple multicore machines, the benchmark implements a blocked matrix multiplication, I ran the code within "strong scaling" over several multicore machines and got different results,

The machines with the different structures are listed below:

| Hosts | OS | RAM | Processor | Sockets | Core per Socket | Thread per Core | L1d | L1i | L2 | L3 | MAX Freq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Host1** | Ubuntu 18.04 | 256 GB | AMD Opteron 6168 | 4 | 12 | 1 | 64K | 64K | 512K | 5118K | 1.9 GHz |
| **Host2** | Ubuntu 18.04 | 1 TB | AMD Opteron 6272 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 16K | 64K | 2048K | 6144K | 1.9 GHz |
| **Host3** | CentOS 7.9.2 | 1 TB | AMD EPYC 7601 | 2 | 32 | 2 | 2M | 2M | 4M | 128M | 2.2 GHz |

on a machine **Host 1**, with the above specification, I got almost linear (ideal) speedup,
I simply ran the following command:

```
mpirun -n $pr --hostfile ~/hosts ./executable --> the hosts file includes only "localhost slots"
```

however, on the **Host 2**, I got speedup but less than the **Host 1** with some "no speedup" on some number of cores, at the end on **Host 3** I got awful results which shows there is sth wrong!

The experiments are the same within the same script to just collect the numbers in a CSV file (I do 10 times of repetition and get the average value for timing measurements). and there is no additional setup to any of these mentioned machines,

Note that the version of MPI on Machines are :

1. Host 1: OpenMPI 2.1.1
2. Host 2: OpenMPI 2.1.1
3. Host 3: OpenMPI 4.1.0

Since I got almost close to linear speedup within Host 1, I think the version of the OpenMPI would not be the case,

Has anybody seen any similar results within mentioned setup?

Comment: No such thing as a "simple benchmark". 1. How large is your matrix? Make sure it doesn't fit in cache. 2. Did you repeat the experiment, with flushing the cache in between if needed? 3. What is a "matrix multiplication"? Times vector or times matrix? 4. Are you making sure not to get "first touch" effects? 5. Are you doing some sort of affinity control?

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Hi there, yes the Matrix size is quite large, 8000 * 8000. I didn't flush the cache, between experiments! the Matrix Multiplication is a vector to Matrix multiplication in a computation kernel. assuming A*B, the Matrix A will be divided into rows based on the number of processors, then each part will be dedicated to a different process, then for "affinity", I didn't control it.

Comment: Make sure you run each test a couple of times in a loop, and throw away the first timing, because that one is polluted by page instantiation, cache loading, whatever.

Comment: Assuming this is a pure MPI benchmark (read no multithreading such as OpenMP), you should always run your benchmarks with `mpirun --bind-to core ...` in order to achieve best and stable performances. If you are running on the local host, you should not need `--hostfile ~/hosts` (it might impact binding, so I recommend you get rid of that option). Also, run with `mpirun --report-bindings ...` to double check the hardware is correctly detected and tasks are pinned accordingly. At first, stick to one SMT thread per core.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Thanks for the comment, I did your suggestions, something that I got from the results is that, for the Host3, it has 128 CPUs (look at the table above), up to 63 CPUs (cores) everything is fine and I have a good speedup, from 64 to 128 it starts to slow down, I think It must be sth related to the architecture topology of the hardware. without a resource manager like Slurm and with pure MPI how I can manage this?

Comment: Unless you know the internals of your application **and** processor, you should have low to moderate expectations with respect to hyperthreading. With Open MPI, do `mpirun --use-hwthread-cpus ...` to have slot == thread (default is slot == core)